# Windows ui automation and Remote Desktop Connection issue

Tags: c#, windows, automation, rdp, rpa

I am facing issue while automating a file upload process through chrome browser.
I have handled the Choose file windows popup. I use the following batch file to log off from remote desktop connnection .

```
for /f "skip=1 tokens=3" %%s in ('query user %USERNAME%') do (
  %windir%\System32\tscon.exe %%s /dest:console
)
```

I have already disabled every setting under **Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Remote Desktop Session Host > Session Time Limits in Windows Group Policy**.

I have used below code for handling the windows file upload dialog

```
    var title = "Open";
                var fileTextBoxName = "File name:";
                var openButtonName = "File name:";

                //File Upload Window
                AutomationElement desktopObject = AutomationElement.RootElement;
                PropertyCondition popUpWindowNameCondition = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, title.Trim());
                AutomationElement popUpWindow = desktopObject.FindFirst(TreeScope.Subtree, popUpWindowNameCondition);
                if (popUpWindow == null) throw new Exception("File Upload dialog window not found");


                //  FileTextBox
                PropertyCondition fileTextBoxCondition = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, fileTextBoxName.Trim());
                AutomationElement fileTextBox = popUpWindow.FindFirst(TreeScope.Subtree,
                    new AndCondition(fileTextBoxCondition,
                    new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Edit)));
                if (fileTextBox == null) throw new Exception("File textbox not found");

                try
                {
                    SetForegroundWindow(popUpWindow, 0);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
                Thread.Sleep(2000);

                try
                {
                    fileTextBox.SetFocus();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }

                ValuePattern etb = fileTextBox.GetCurrentPattern(ValuePattern.Pattern) as ValuePattern;
                etb.SetValue(extractedFields["UploadFilePath"].ToString());

                Thread.Sleep(2000);

                PropertyCondition buttonCondition = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Open");
                AutomationElement buttonElement = popUpWindow.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, buttonCondition);
                if (buttonElement == null) throw new Exception("Button not found");
                try
                {
                    AutomationElement button = buttonElement;
                    InvokePattern buttonPattern = button.GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern) as InvokePattern;
                    buttonPattern.Invoke();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    SendKeys.SendWait("{Enter}");
                }

   static int RETRY_LIMIT = 3;
        public static bool SetForegroundWindow(AutomationElement elm, uint retries, int time = 2000)
        {
            try
            {
                if (retries < RETRY_LIMIT)
                {
                    // Using Win32 to set foreground window because
                    // AutomationElement.SetFocus() is unreliable

                    // Get handle to the element
                    IntPtr other = FindWindow(null, elm.Current.Name);

                    // Get the Process ID for the element we are trying to
                    // set as the foreground element
                    int other_id = GetWindowThreadProcessId(
                        other, IntPtr.Zero);

                    // Get the Process ID for the current process
                    int this_id = GetWindowThreadProcessId(
                        Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle, IntPtr.Zero);

                    // Attach the current process's input to that of the 
                    // given element. We have to do this otherwise the
                    // WM_SETFOCUS message will be ignored by the element.
                    bool success =
                        AttachThreadInput(this_id, other_id, true);

                    // Make the Win32 call
                    IntPtr previous = SetForegroundWindow(other);

                    if (IntPtr.Zero.Equals(previous))
                    {
                        // Trigger re-try
                        throw new Exception(
                            "SetForegroundWindow failed");
                    }
                    return true;
                }

                // Exceeded retry limit, failed!
                return false;
            }
            catch
            {
                retries++;
                Thread.Sleep(time);
                return SetForegroundWindow(elm, retries);
            }
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern bool AttachThreadInput(int idAttach, int idAttachTo, bool fAttach);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern int GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lpdwProcessId);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern IntPtr SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
```

The code works perfectly after disconnecting from RDP using above bat. But the issue starts afters approx 12 hours. There is no error logged in the log file. (I have removed the logs from below code for keeping it small). The code finds the open dialog box and even the file textbox. The log says it has entered the file path. And even the open button is clicked . But actually the file is not selected . The website throws a alert prompting for selecting the file on pressing the upload button. The issue is only resolved when i reconnect to RDP and use the above bat to disconnect from RDP. I want to know is there any possibility for the code to work without reconnecting to RDP after every 12 hours ?

Comment: Have you tried moving the mouse every minute?

Comment: Like programmatically?? Can you give an example please with .net ?

Comment: Please try MouseHandler from this nuget library: https://github.com/quellatalo/TheHands